# Testar conexao ao banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho uma aplicação que possui um banco de dados central, nele é realizado o cadastro de vários bancos de dados dinamicamente para usar em outra parte da aplicação. Quero saber como testar se existe conexão a esse banco de dados.

Atualmente tenho essa função em um `helper` para facilitar a configuração:

```
function configure_database($database, $username, $password) {
   $db['hostname'] = 'localhost';
   $db['username'] = $username;
   $db['password'] = $password;
   $db['database'] = $database;
   $db['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
   $db['dbprefix'] = '';
   $db['pconnect'] = FALSE;
   $db['db_debug'] = TRUE;
   $db['cache_on'] = FALSE;
   $db['cachedir'] = '';
   $db['char_set'] = 'utf8';
   $db['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
   $db['swap_pre'] = '';
   $db['autoinit'] = TRUE;
   $db['stricton'] = FALSE;
   return $db;
}
```

Ai na hora de conectar faço o seguinte:

```
$database = $this->load->database(configure_database($name_database, $user_database, $password_database), TRUE);
```

Existe alguma forma de testar a variável `$database` para verificar se existe uma conexão ou se deu erro para validar o cadastro do banco de dados?

Lembrando que é um sistema que se conecta a múltiplos bancos de dados e essas configurações do banco não são fixas, não podendo deixar em um array fixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com [essa resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517942/4336024):

Desabilite a inicialização automática do banco do dados:

```
$db['autoinit'] = FALSE;
```

Para evitar erros surpresa, desabilite a depuração:

```
$db['debug'] = FALSE;
```

Utilize a função `initialize()` para verificar:

```
$database = $this->load->database(configure_database($name_database, $user_database, $password_database), TRUE);
$connected = $database->initialize();
if (!$connected) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Essa solução resolveu, obrigado, conforme a resposta do link precisei mudar as opções das configurações e deixar assim. $db['db_debug'] = FALSE; $db['autoinit'] = FALSE;

Comment: Entendi. Então vou adicionar a essa resposta pra ajudar outros usuários :)